# Does Linux consider a "kB" to be 1000 or 1024 bytes?

Tags: linux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581540/should-i-look-at-vmsize-vmrss-or-some-combination-for-memory-stats-on-linux

I'm simply wondering if these "kB" correspond to 1000 or 1024 bytes.

Comment: It is common to use both (base 10 and base 2). Often kB means 1000 B and kiB means 1024 B (and corresponding: MB and MiB, GB and GiB. Some tools let you switch between the ways to show size, for example with the command `df`: `df -h` (alias `df --human-readable`) and `df -H` (alias 'df --si`).

Comment: @sudodus What about in this specific case? It's important to get this right...

Comment: What particular case? All we see here is a link to some other question. Please [edit] and put all relevant information into _this_ question so the question can stand alone and anyone who reads it can understand what you are asking.

Comment: First of all, we expect users on these sites to follow the Code of Conduct and be civil with other users. Your comment was out of line and has been deleted. Second, I did not vote on this question one way or the other. I asked you to include all relevant information _here_ and not just dump a link and expect people to guess what you need. As you can see, your question is getting downvotes and that is precisely because you are not giving any information. The clearer your question, the better your chances of getting an answer. Your call.

Comment: It would depend on what you are doing. If you can are referring to logical volumes, then that can be specified with, for example, `GB` or `GiB` or `TB` or `TIB`. It would be up to you and not the operating system.

Answer (score 5):

When shown in output from the kernel (*e.g.* under `/proc`), “kB” means 1024 bytes.